# Multiplication in a variable

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code that needs to multiply numbers by different values, all the code for the entering and validation of the 7 digit number works however the multiplication doesn't work.  This is my code.

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("enter a 7 digit number: "))
        check = len(str(num))

        if check == 7:
            print("This code is valid")
            break

        else:
            num = int(input("enter a number that is only 7 digits: "))

    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer")


num = int(num)        

def multiplication():
    num[0]*3
    num[1]*1
    num[2]*3
    num[3]*1
    num[4]*3
    num[5]*1
    num[6]*3
    return total

multiplication()
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "\\hpdl3802\stuhomefolders$\12waj066\Year 10\Computing\A453\Code\Test v2.py", line 29, in <module> 
>     multiplication() 
>   File "\\hpdl3802\stuhomefolders$\12waj066\Year 10\Computing\A453\Code\Test v2.py", line 20, in multiplication 
>     num[0]*3 
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Any feedback is welcome

Comment: How it doesn't work? did you get any error?

Comment: You are returning `total` but `total` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: i am receiving the following error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\hpdl3802\stuhomefolders$\12waj066\Year 10\Computing\A453\Code\Test v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    multiplication()
  File "\\hpdl3802\stuhomefolders$\12waj066\Year 10\Computing\A453\Code\Test v2.py", line 20, in multiplication
    num[0]*3
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: what's the point of the `num[x]*y` stuff? those multiplication results aren't stored anywhere, and you never assign anything to `total`, nor output anything after you do return.

Comment: The `else` case is not necessary, because you're repeating the `while` loop, and overwrite the read value, anyway.

Comment: The code works now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Of course, your code might be written in a number of ways, optimized (check @Kasravand answer, it's awesome) or not, but with a minimal effort this is what I get:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = input("enter a 7 digit number: ")
        check = len(num)
        int(num) # will trigger ValueError if not a number

        if check == 7:
            print("This code is valid")
            break
        else:
            print("bad length, try again")

    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer")

def multiplication(num):
    total  = int(num[0])*3
    total += int(num[1])*1
    total += int(num[2])*3
    total += int(num[3])*1
    total += int(num[4])*3
    total += int(num[5])*1
    total += int(num[6])*3

    return total

print("Answer: ", multiplication(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you convert the input number to an integer you can not use indexing on that object since integers don't support indexing. If you want to multiply your digits by a specific number you better do this before converting to integer.

So first off replace the following part:

```
num = int(input("enter a number that is only 7 digits: "))
```

with:

```
num = input("enter a number that is only 7 digits: ")
```

The you can use `repeat` and `chain` functions from `itertools` module in order to create your repeated numbers, then use a list comprehension to calculate the multiplication:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> N = 7
>>> li = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat([3, 1], N/2 + 1)))
>>> num = '1290286'
>>> [i * j for i, j in zip(map(int, num), li)]
[3, 2, 27, 0, 6, 8, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're bound to use an integer instead of a list for the input, you can do one of the following:

You could access the individual digits using a combination of integer division and modulo, for example:

```
first_digit = num // 1000000 * 3
second_digit = num // 100000 % 10 * 1
# and so on
```

Or you could get the input as a string and access and convert the individual digits:

```
# [...]
num = input("enter a number that is only 7 digits: ")
# [...]
first_digit = int(num[0]) * 3
second_digit = int(num[1]) * 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will works:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("enter a 7 digit number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer")

    else:

        if len(str(num)) != 7:
            print("enter a number that is only 7 digits")            
        else:
            break

num = str(num)

def multiplication():
    total = 0 
    for i,m in enumerate([3,1,3,1,3,1,3]):        
       total += int(num[i])*m   # transform the index of text into a integer

    return total

print(multiplication())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
    num = ''
    check = 0
    while True:
        try:
            num = raw_input("enter a 7 digit number: ")
            check = len(num)

            if check == 7:
                print("This code is valid")
                break

            else:
                print "enter a number that is only 7 digits"

        except ValueError:
            print("you must enter an integer")


    def multiplication():
        total = 0
        for i in range(check):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                total += int(num[i]) * 3
            else:
                total += int(num[i]) * 1

        print total

    multiplication()
```